# .htaccess redirect for multiple IP ranges

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ip, ip-address

I am trying to redirect multiple different IP addresses except those that match a specific user-agent. So far I've been able to successfully do this with 1 IP range, eg:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.123\.123\.[0-9]{1,3}$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^useragent$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.redirecthere.com/$1 [L]
```

So the above redirects the IPs 123.123.123.x to the URL - unless that IP has this useragent, in which case no redirect takes place.

I actually need  to redirect several other IP ranges as well as this. But doing so as follows breaks everything:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.123\.123\.[0-9]{1,3}$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^124\.124\.124\.[0-9]{1,3}$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^useragent$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.redirecthere.com/$1 [L]
```

What am I doing wrong? I wasn't able to find any duplicate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `[OR]` because the normal test is "AND":

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.123\.123\.[0-9]{1,3}$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^125\.125\.125\.[0-9]{1,3}$ [OR]
#.....
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^124\.124\.124\.[0-9]{1,3}$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^useragent$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.redirecthere.com/$1 [L]
```